# JavasScript inheritance for constructors that return a function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Is there a way in JavaScript to inherit from a constructor function that returns a function? For example:

```
var A = function() {
  return function(input) {
    // do stuff
  };
};

var B = function() {};
B.prototype = new A();
var b = new B();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning a function from your constructor, you're not creating an instance of `A`, but rather an instance of the function. Therefore, inheritance will not work.

```
var A = function() { return function(input) {}; };
var a = new A();
>>> typeof a;
"function"

var A = function() {};
var a = new A();
>>> typeof a;
"object"
```

If you need `B` to inherit the returned function from `A`, you should set it as a method of `A`, either locally or in the prototype chain, and pass it that way.

```
var A = function() {
  this.method = function(input) {}
};

var B = function() {}
B.prototype = new A();
var b = new B();
>>> b.method
'function(input) { }'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up using composition over inheritance to reduce duplication - I'd recommend it to any folks using constructors in this factory-esque way.